# Question on conditional join or other way to create view based on two tables in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to create a view that combines these two materialized views with following rules.

- if all_products.id and there is matching id (market_id not relevant) in visible_products then only return visible_products rows
- if all_products.id and there is no matching id in visible_products (market_id is not relevant in match) then return rows from all_products

I am not able to figure it out with joins or union. Can this be solved with a case statement? If both tables have rows then inner join will give me the correct result and if visible_products have no matching rows a left join will work but I need a join or other solution that will work with both cases.

Both all_products and visible_products are materialzied views that I can change / add columns to if needed.

Example a

```
all_products
id, market_id
1, 100
1, 101
1, 102

visible_products
id, market_id
1, 100

result product_view
1,100
```

Example b

```
all_products
id, market_id
2, 103
2, 104
2, 105

visible_products
id, market_id

result product_view
2, 103
2, 104
2, 105
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.market_id
FROM all_products a
INNER JOIN visible_products v ON v.id=a.id AND v.market_id=a.market_ID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM all_products a
       INNER JOIN visible_products v ON v.id=a.id AND v.market_id=a.market_ID
      )

UNION ALL

SELECT a.id, a.market_id
FROM all_products a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM all_products a
       INNER JOIN visible_products v ON v.id=a.id AND v.market_id=a.market_ID
      )
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the second select is not working correctly for ex b. I will need to set up a better test tomorrow though as its late here and it worked on a small test. I think it could be when there is more id's in all_products it fails somehow. But thanks I think its close

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example @luuk wrote I got it working by changing it slightly to the below code (work in progress). It is however too slow as the two tables are really big (1m+rows). Not sure if it is easier to have two separate queries and then programatically figure out which to pick or if I can't rethink this.

```
SELECT a.id, a.market_id
FROM all_products a
INNER JOIN visible_products v ON v.id=a.id AND v.market_id=a.market_ID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM all_products a
       INNER JOIN visible_products v ON v.id=a.id AND v.market_id=a.market_ID
      )

UNION ALL

SELECT   
    ap.id, 
    ap.market_id
    FROM all_products ap
    WHERE ap.id NOT IN
        (SELECT vp.id 
        FROM visible_products vp)
```

Comment: I think it was late yesterday when I typed this.... If I look at the first part (before the `UNION ALL`, it's  can be simplified because it currently says `SELECT records WHERE there are records in the SELECT`, the compete `WHERE`-clause can be deleted.

Comment: About the secons part (after the `UNION ALL`) , maybe performance gets better when you do `SELECT … FROM all_products ap LEFT JOIN visible_products vp ON vp.id=ap.id WHERE vp.id SI NULL`